# menu item не активна, когда указываешь action

Tags: c, gtk3

появляется popover menu, но выбрать item не могу. не могу найти правильного решения в документации.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

GtkApplication *app;

static void window_destroy_cb ( GtkWidget *window, gpointer data ) {
    ( void ) data;

    g_application_quit ( ( GApplication * ) app );
    exit ( EXIT_SUCCESS );
}

static void action_test_activate_cb ( GSimpleAction *action, GVariant *parameter, gpointer data ) {
    g_application_quit ( ( GApplication * ) app );
    exit ( EXIT_SUCCESS );
}

static void action_new_file_cb ( GSimpleAction *simple, GVariant *parameter, gpointer data ) {
    g_application_quit ( ( GApplication * ) app );
    exit ( EXIT_SUCCESS );
}

static GSimpleActionGroup *create_actions ( ) {
    const GActionEntry entries[] = {
        { "action_new_file", action_new_file_cb }
    };

    GSimpleActionGroup *group;

    group = g_simple_action_group_new ( );
    g_action_map_add_action_entries ( ( GActionMap * ) group, entries, G_N_ELEMENTS ( entries ), NULL );

    return group;
}

static void app_activate_cb ( GtkApplication *app, gpointer data ) {
    ( void ) data;

    GtkWidget *widget_window = gtk_application_window_new ( app );
    g_signal_connect ( widget_window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK ( window_destroy_cb ), NULL );

    GSimpleActionGroup *g_action_group = create_actions ( );

    GMenu *gmenu_menu = g_menu_new ( );
    g_menu_append ( gmenu_menu, "Создать файл", "action_new_file" );
    GtkWidget *widget_menu = gtk_menu_button_new ( );

    GtkWidget *widget_popover = gtk_popover_new_from_model ( widget_menu, ( GMenuModel * ) gmenu_menu );

    gtk_menu_button_set_popover ( ( GtkMenuButton * ) widget_menu, widget_popover );

    GtkWidget *widget_header = gtk_header_bar_new ( );
    gtk_header_bar_set_title ( ( GtkHeaderBar * ) widget_header, "db_network_guard" );
    gtk_header_bar_set_show_close_button ( ( GtkHeaderBar * ) widget_header, TRUE );
    gtk_header_bar_set_decoration_layout ( ( GtkHeaderBar * ) widget_header, "menu:minimize,maximize,close" );
    gtk_header_bar_pack_end ( ( GtkHeaderBar * ) widget_header, widget_menu );


    gtk_window_set_titlebar ( ( GtkWindow * ) widget_window, widget_header );

    gtk_widget_show_all ( widget_window );
}

int main ( int argc, char **argv ) {
    app = gtk_application_new ( "org.xverizex.db_nguard", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE );
    g_application_register ( ( GApplication * ) app, NULL, NULL );
    g_signal_connect ( app, "activate", G_CALLBACK ( app_activate_cb ), NULL );
    return g_application_run ( ( GApplication * ) app, argc, argv );
}
```

Comment: но если сделать так `g_menu_append ( gmenu_menu, "Создать файл", NULL );`, то кнопка активна, но конечно же без действия.

Answer (score 0):

наконецто нашел в чем дело. У `action_map` должно быть окно. и указывать в меню действия как `win.action`.

```
static GActionEntry entries[] = {
        { "action_new_file", action_new_file_cb, NULL, NULL, NULL }
};

static void create_actions ( GtkWidget *window ) {

        g_action_map_add_action_entries ( ( GActionMap * ) window, entries, G_N_ELEMENTS ( entries ), NULL );
}

static void app_activate_cb ( GtkApplication *app, gpointer data ) {
        ( void ) data;

        GtkWidget *widget_window = gtk_application_window_new ( app );
        g_signal_connect ( widget_window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK ( window_destroy_cb ), NULL );


        create_actions ( widget_window );
        GMenu *gmenu_menu = g_menu_new ( );
        g_menu_append ( gmenu_menu, "Создать файл", "win.action_new_file" );

        gtk_application_set_app_menu ( app, ( GMenuModel * ) gmenu_menu );
        GtkWidget *widget_menu = gtk_menu_button_new ( );
```